# when i append element to an a global array its replaced with the previous elements (strange behavior )?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

```
    if products == nil {
        products = [Product]()
        products!.append(product!)

        arr.append(product)
    }else{
        products!.append(product!)

        arr.append(product)
    }
```

forexample if i want to duplicate the product in my shopping cart with different properties for each one of them such as changing the size or quantity i press the button ...but what i get is adding number products which is correct but with same last product properties for all products ! any diea ?

Comment: My guess: Product is a class and you always append the same instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you use the same object `product!` and change it's properties then re-append it which is incorrect as it's a reference type , you need  creation of product

```
let prod = Product(////////)
```

Comment: var size : String = "M"
    
    enum sizeCases : String {
        case M = "M"
        case L = "L"
        case XL = "XL"
        case XXL = "XXL"
    }
    
    var product : Product! {
        didSet{
            updateUI()
            }
    }

Comment: No this `var product : Product! ` should be for every object , whereEver you get to add new properties create the object again , make it local

Comment: since it's class reference changing properties will be for all you can copy it but it's advanced step and no need for it , so create the object every time you get new properties

Comment: im getting the product from the TableViewController ... and im doing the modifying in the cell ... how i do it with keeping observer  on product ?!